# Crontab - How to verify a PHP script Runs Successfully or not in a Cronjob Shell Script?

Tags: centos, php, cron

I have below crontab in the system (Centos 7.9), However i am unable to verify if this runs correctly or not,

***i.e if the crontab finds the PHP enr. variables or if the crontab has executed correctly without any errors in the shell or if the crontab entry has syntax issue ..etc***

Any suggestion on how to do debug or capturing the output of a crontab like this one below

```
0 */1 * * * /var/www/example.com/scripts/cron.sh >> /var/log/app/cron/cron.log
```

Script content is like below

```
[root@]# cat /var/www/example.com/scripts/cron.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /var/www/example.com/public
php cron.php
```

Is there better way to do this?

Comment: I suggest that you add a crontab entry for `/usr/bin/false` and then watch what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following

```
$ echo $?
```

If you get `0`  meaning is OK, a other value over 0 is not ok.

($?) Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.